# Clean and Rebind Data using KnockoutJs Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

**So I bind my Knockout template as follows:**

**First ajax, get data then I pass the data can call a function named bindKo:**

```
function bindKo(data) {
            var length = data.length;
            var insertRecord = {};

            if (length > 0) {
                insertRecord = data[data.length - 1]; //last record is an empty PremlimViewModel for insert
                insertRecord.Add = true;
                data.splice(data.length - 1, 1); //remove that blank insert record
            }

            function prelims(data) {
                var self = this;
                var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { copy: ["_destroy"] }, self);


                self.BidPriceFormatted = ko.computed({
                    read: function () {
                        var bidPrice = this.BidPrice();
                        if (bidPrice) {
                            if (!isNaN(bidPrice)) {
                                var input = '<input type="text" value="' + bidPrice + '"/>';
                                return $(input).currency({ decimals: 0 }).val();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    write: function (value) {
                        value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
                        this.BidPrice(value);
                    },
                    owner: this
                });

                return model;
            }

            var mapping = {
                create: function (options) {
                    return new prelims(options.data);
                }
            };

            function viewModel(prelimData) {
                var self = this;


                self.prelims = ko.mapping.fromJS(prelimData, mapping);
                self.remove = function (prelim) {
                    self.prelims.destroy(prelim);
                };
                self.addOption = function () {
                    var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, insertRecord);

                    self.prelims.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(clone));
                };
            }

            ViewModel = new viewModel(data);
            ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
        }
```

**I have a template defined where you can add and remove records, and user does just that:**

```
<script type="text/html" id="PrelimsTemplate">
<!--Template Goodness-->
</script>
```

**Then, ajax call, records updated in datanbase, latest results returned and I do:**

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(newestData, ViewModel)
```

**But this does not work because my ViewModel is complex.
So I would just like to reBind the template entirely. Make is disappear and reappear with latest data.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your template in a `container` than you can hook onto with `jQuery`.

When you need to trash it use `ko.cleanNode` and jQuery `.empty()`

```
emptyTemplate: function(){
  ko.cleanNode($('#template-container')[0]);
  $('#template-container').empty();
}
```

Load your template back up

```
fillTemplate: function(){
    $('#template-container').html('<div data-bind="template: {name:\'templateId\', data: $data}"></div>');

    ko.applyBindings(data,$('#template-container')[0])
},
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/ru5uD/)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up simplifying some of my code, I had a method that was AddUpdateDelete and all was handled in one package update to the server. A bit much, I should have noticed, I separated into Add, Delete and Update methods and when an Add or Delete is done, I immediately update server and do not have such a complex ViewModel to refresh anymore.